# Как вывести элемент в определенном месте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как элемент `.block` перенести не просто в `.wrp`, а вывести его после определенного (например, третьего или четвертого) блока `.news`? При этом в блоке `.wrp` может быть сколько угодно блоков `.news`. Благодарю!

```js
$('.block').detach().prependTo('.wrp');
```

```css
.wrp,
.news{
display:block;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}
.news {
background-color:beige;
margin: 5px 0;
}
.block {
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
width:200px;
height:20px;
background-color:chocolate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrp">
<div class="news">Блок 1</div>
<div class="news">Блок 2</div>
<div class="news">Блок 3</div>
<div class="news">Блок 4</div>
<div class="news">Блок 5</div>
<div class="news">Блок 6</div>
<div class="news">Блок 7</div>
</div>
<div class="block">Перемещаемый блок</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На помощь приходят:

- **[insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/) | [.insertAfter (описание на русском)](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)**

  и
- **[eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) | [eq (описание на русском)](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%83)**

```js
$('.block').detach().insertAfter('.wrp .news:eq(2)');
```

```css
.wrp,
.news{
display:block;
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
}
.news {
background-color:beige;
margin: 5px 0;
}
.block {
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
width:200px;
height:20px;
background-color:chocolate;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrp">
<div class="news">Блок 1</div>
<div class="news">Блок 2</div>
<div class="news">Блок 3</div>
<div class="news">Блок 4</div>
<div class="news">Блок 5</div>
<div class="news">Блок 6</div>
<div class="news">Блок 7</div>
</div>
<div class="block">Перемещаемый блок</div>
```

Comment: @LADYX можно и галку шмякнуть)